# Bootstrap table hover for rows with same column value

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to ask you for a tips how would you do that. I'am using bootstrap tables with hover on rows. But I need to hover more rows which have same value in specific (first column). So when I hover one of those rows which have same value in first corner all rows with this value will change a color.

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Add a class and hover the rows with the same class.

Comment: Html code is generated dynamically, it must be based on column value. So I'm looking for some sample of jquery code which solves this part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a bootstrap issue... See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rXcUP/):

```
$('.item').on('mouseenter', function(){
    var value = $(this).text()

    $('.item').each(function(){
        $this = $(this);
        if(value == $this.text()){
            $this.addClass('active');
        }
    });
});

$('.item').on('mouseleave', function() {
    $('.item').each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

Hope this helps!